# Android 2.2: Screen doesn't wake up after timeout when brightness set to zero

Tags: android-2.2-froyo, screen-brightness

Im using the following code to adjust the brightness of the screen:

```
public void SetBright(float value) {
    Window mywindow = getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = mywindow.getAttributes();

    lp.screenBrightness = value;
    mywindow.setAttributes(lp);        
}
```

But i want the brightness to be 0% for a specific time. But when i use `SetBright(0.0f)`, i cant change it back. I made a timer that runs for a minute with 0% brightness, then turns it back to 100%. Works when i use 10% for example. But when i turn it to 0% i cant seem to wake it up again. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Try this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

Comment: Thanks but "Device battery life will be significantly affected by the use of this API". Is there any other way?

Comment: As per i know if you wanna keep screen brighten then it always use battery to keep it bright. Right???

Comment: Yes, but i want sure if they were refering to the screen beeing on. Anyway, i get an error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Wakelock under-locked My tag". Any clue what might be wrong?